# How to trigger jquery event from an ajax auto suggest list

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a `div` which slides in when u hover elements with a particular `ID`. I use **jQuery** for sliding in. 
I have a search feature which populates a list with elements that are searched for by an **ajax** call(raw **ajax** call, not using **jQuery**) to a **php** file which then searches the database and populates the list.

The problem is I want to slide in the `div` when the list element in the auto suggest list 
is clicked. I thought this could be done by a simple addition of the same id name so that **jQuery** picks up that and slides the **div** in. But that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions would help.

The main problem is that **jQuery** doesn't pick up the id of the element that is in the list being populated via the **ajax** call.

Jquery code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mirror_content").hide(); 
    $('#mir_way').mouseover(function(){ 
    $('.mirror').stop().animate({width:"1109px", opacity: 1 ,  margin: "0 235px 
      0 0"}, 100, function() {
        $('.mirror_content').fadeIn('slow'); 
    })
});
$('#mir_way').mouseup(function(){
    $('.mirror_content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.mirror').stop().animate({width : "0",opacity : 0.1},100);
    });
});
$('#close').click(function(){
    $('.mirror_content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('.mirror').stop().animate({width : "0",opcaity : 0.1},100);
    });
});
$('#close').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.mirror').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4} , 400);
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.mirror').stop().animate({opacity : 1},400);
});

$(window).mouseup(function(e){
    if ($('.mirror').has(e.target).length === 0){
        $('.mirror_content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('.mirror').stop().animate({width:"0", opacity : 0.1},        
      100);
        });
    }
}); 
    $(window).keyup(function(event) {
     if(event.which === 27) {
        $('.mirror_content').fadeOut('slow', function() { 
            $('.mirror').stop().animate({width:"0", opacity:0.1}, 100);

        });
     }
  });

 });
```

php code which populates the auto suggest :

```
  <a href="#" id = "mir_way" style = "text-decoration : none;">
  <li class = "search_item">
  <span class = "search_name"><?php echo $firstname.'&nbsp;'.$lastname.'<br>'; ?></span>
  <span class = "sec_line"><?php echo $gender; ?></span>
  </li></a>
```

Comment: @KamilT: I have updated the post with code...

Comment: Can you add more html/code. I see you have a click event for "#close" but where is the jquery event that clicks on your list and gets the id of the selected element then calls your list to slide in? Maybe add some comments to your code